# Java to re-read environment keycodes?

Tags: java, unix

I have a really nasty problem. My java application is running on unix and I'm using VNC to connect (from windows). The problem is that VNC has some issues with registering non-ansi keysum's.

> KbdAddEvent: unknown KeySym 0xc0 -
>   allocating KeyCode 117

Even so, keyboard input works correctly in xterm, mozilla and etc. But when I'm using java for this keycodes to work, I need first to enter them wiht my keyboard (all of them, so VNC can allocate them), and after that to start java.

So my question is, is there a way running java instance to re-read keycodes from environment, so for me to be able to use non-ansi keycodes without typing them first, and only after that starting some java application.